# exporting a table element to a xlsx file, with borders

Tags: php, html-table, phpexcel

I want to export a html table element to a xlsx file, with borders.

I can do it with xls (not xlsx). With xls, Excel can open any html file and convert the content, including the borders. For xlsx, I have to use PHPExcel, but I cannot format my table (adding borders...).

I can export to a xlsx with the code below, but there are no borders :

```
   <?php
    require_once '/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    $file=$_POST['file']."_".date("ymd").".xlsx";
    $table = "<table border='1'>".$_POST['table']."</table>";
    $table = mb_convert_encoding($table, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8'); 
    $table = "\xFF\xFE" . $table;

    // save $table inside temporary file that will be deleted later
    $tmpfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'html');
    file_put_contents($tmpfile, $table);

    // insert $table into $objPHPExcel's Active Sheet through $excelHTMLReader
    $objPHPExcel     = new PHPExcel();

    $excelHTMLReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('HTML');
    $excelHTMLReader->loadIntoExisting($tmpfile, $objPHPExcel);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('biblio_uq9_excel'); // Change sheet's title if you want

    unlink($tmpfile); // delete temporary file because it isn't needed anymore

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'); // header for .xlxs file
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$file); // specify the download file name
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    // Creates a writer to output the $objPHPExcel's content
    $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $writer->save('php://output');
    exit;

    ?>
```

EDIT : See my answer below. There's nothing we can do. Excel .xlsx format does not allow for auto-conversion of delimited/markup file.

Answer (score 0):

It's all native Excel.

Older Excel (.xls) allowed opening directly a delimited text file or a markup file (xml, html), which Excel converts correctly. Excel can also convert somme css styling, like applying border like this : `<table border=1>`

New Excel (.xlsx) doesn't allow that, so a tool like PHPExcel is needed. PHPExcel converts the html table to pure Excel, but we lose all formating.